# How do I change/increment or use a db to change an audio onclick button?

Tags: javascript, php, database, audio, onclick

So I am trying to create an onclick for the same buttons by incrementing the name of the song and the `id` for the incremented song, but I cant seem to fetch the correct `id` in js, I always gets the first song played when I press all of the buttons. I thought of trying to save each as a cookie and then refering the buttons with different `ids` as cookies, or even trying to making use of `$_SESSIONS`, so I'll gladly take any suggestions

```
              <!DOCTYPE HTML>
             <?php
             session_start();
             //connecting to mysql db
              include ('Oppkobling.php');


                // making an sql query
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM Band';

                // running the query
                $resultat = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                // saving results to an variable
                $antall = mysqli_num_rows($resultat);

                // creating a table
                echo('<table class="per">');
                 echo('<tr><th>Navn</th><th>Land</th><th>Avspillinger</th>
               <th>Sjanger</th><th>Logo</th><th id=due>Top sang</th></tr>');
                // loop for the table
                for ($i=0; $i < $antall; $i++)
                {

                    $rad = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat);
                    echo('<tr><td>
                '.$rad['Band'].'</td><td>
                '.$rad['Land'].'</td><td>
                '.$rad['Avspillinger'].'</td><td>
                '.$rad['Sjanger'].'</td><td>
                <img src = "./bilder/'.$rad['Bilde'].' "id=due></td><td>
                '//this part is where my audio is implemented
                '
                <audio src="sang'.$rad['Sang'].'.mp3"." id="ip'.$i.'">
                </audio><img src="button.png" onclick="audio.play()" width= 
                "100px"height="100px"></td></tr>');
              }
              echo('</table>');

                // disconnecting from db
                mysqli_close($db);
                mysqli_free_result($resultat);
            ?>
            <html>
            <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
              <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           //I dont know how to solve it at all
           var i;
            i = -1;
          for (i){
           var c = "ip"+i;}
           var x = document.getElementById(c).src;
           var audio = new Audio(x);
              audio.onclick = function(){
              audio.play();
            }
              audio.loop = false;
          </script>
           </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You **thought** of trying but didn't try anything that so ever, and looking for a suggestion, are you aware that it goes against the rules?

Comment: You should create a function and feed the id into it to act on then use that function as the `onclick` or you can create an event listener on a class and use `this` to isolate what is being acted on.